# What does "19:40:25 LOG (Perf): DgnSAPI paused -> BeginUtt = 158 msec" indicate in Dragon NaturallySpeaking's log?

Tags: dragon-naturally-speaking

In Dragon NaturallySpeaking's log (in my case located in `C:\Users\Joey\AppData\Roaming\Nuance\NaturallySpeaking12\Dragon.log`), I can see statements such as:

```
19:40:25 LOG (Perf): DgnSAPI paused -> BeginUtt = 158 msec
[...]
19:41:41 LOG (Perf): DgnSAPI paused -> BeginUtt = 154 msec
[...]
19:41:56 LOG (Perf): DgnSAPI paused -> BeginUtt = 172 msec
```

What does the time expressed in milliseconds at the end of the line indicate?

Comment: The only people likely to able to answer that are the developers ...

Comment: @DavidPostill developers and superusers!